# Fuse 7.1.0 - Blueprint- Bundle entering grace period : Missing dependencies error : cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty

Tags: jbossfuse, blueprint-osgi

My bundle is entering grace period with the following error:

karaf@root()> bundle:diag

### BundleNameXYZ [bundle-name-xyz] (228)

Status: GracePeriod
Blueprint
2/15/19 4:31 PM
Missing dependencies:
(&(objectClass=org.apache.aries.blueprint.NamespaceHandler)(osgi.service.blueprint.namespace=http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http-jetty/configuration))
Declarative Services
CdiOsgi

My blueprint.xml file contains

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
xmlns:http-conf="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint" xmlns:http-jetty="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http-jetty/configuration"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
   http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd
   http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http-jetty/configuration http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-jetty.xsd
   http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd">
```

..............

I've tried installing required features like camel-jetty-common, camel-jetty9, camel-cxf-transport. Also tried adding provided scope in pom.xml as in

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Checked out some solutions available on JBoss and stackoverflow forums.Still no luck. Could someone help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Fuse 7 officially supports undertow instead of jetty. Jetty server-side is blacklisted. Please check cxf-rt-transports-http-undertow.

Comment: Tried adding that as dependency but same result. I added cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty to build.plugins.plugin.configuration.instructions.Embed-Dependency and now bundle status is changed from 'Grace Period' to 'Installed'.

Comment: The log now shows        org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve bundle-name-xyz [228](R 228.18): missing requirement [bundle-name-xyz [228](R 228.18)] osgi.wiring
.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.context)(version>=3.0.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))

Comment: so you're missing spring features / bundles.